# How to Use CSS Selector in Google Tag Manager do Get a Name

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

Im new with Google Tag Manager and need help with it.

I need to create a var with an item that is inside this block:

```
<script id="tutor-script-js-extra">
var _tutorobject = {"ajaxurl":"https:example"}
```

How do i create a tag to get this ajaxurl into a variable in GTM?

In new and on fing examples to tag inside classes